# how to change value in selenium List <Webelement>

Tags: java, list, selenium, testing, arraylist

i am trying to get a value from List and then change the value if its not what i expect. what i am trying to do is navigate to next page. the website has "previous", "1" and so on. i want to get "previous" from the list and then change it to "2" so that i will be able to navigate forward. please let me know if i am able to explain well.Please see my below code, is there any way i could change the list value? what i am doing is not working:

```
try {
            nextPage_02 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'=sr_pg_')]"));

if (nextPage_02 != null || ((WebElement) nextPage_02).isDisplayed()) {
                for(WebElement g : nextPage_02) {
                    if(g.getText().equals("previous")) {
                        g.getText().replace("previous", "0") ;
                        System.out.println(g.getText());
                        int nextPageToInt = Integer.parseInt(g.getText());
                        int nextPage_content ;
                        int i ;
                        for(i= 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
                            nextPage_content = nextPageToInt + i;
                            if(nextPageToInt == nextPage_content ) {
                                ((WebElement) nextPage_02).click();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to change the list value on site?

Comment: The String `g.getText()` exists inside the `for` block only.
If you call `g.getText()` another time, you'll get the WebElement's original text.

Comment: what i am trying to do is navigate to next page. the website has "previous", "1" and so on. i want to get "previous" from the list and then change it to "2" so that i will be able to navigate forward. please let me know if i am able to explain well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value that you get from list instead of changing the list value on webpage, you can do like this:

```java
try {
    public static List<WebElement> nextPage_02 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'=sr_pg_')]"));
    for (WebElement g : nextPage_02) {
        String str = g.getText();
        if(str.equals("someText")) {
            str = str.replaceAll("someText", "2") ;
            int nextPageToInt = Integer.parseInt(str);
            // do something with nextPageToInt??
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to change the list value on webpage, please let us know more about your true intentions.